# Thue's Theorem of Diophantine approximation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations, diophantine-approximation

**Edit added for the Bounty: the following question is an old one (without a definitive answer). I faced the same issue, so I hope that someone could complete the given answer**

---

I'm trying to read the book Lecture Notes on Diophantine Analysis by Zannier and he says that the following theorems are equivalent:

Theorem 1.  Let $\xi$ be an algebraic real number of degree $d\geq 3$. For every $\epsilon >0$ there is a number $\gamma >0$ such that for all $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$ $q>0$ 
$$|\xi-\frac{p}{q}|>\frac{\gamma}{q^{1+\frac{d}{2}+\epsilon}}$$

Theorem 2. Let $\xi$ be an algebraic real number of degree $d\geq 3$. For every $\epsilon >0$ there are only finitely many rationals $\frac{p}{q}$ with $q>0$ such that 
$$|\xi-\frac{p}{q}|<\frac{1}{q^{1+\frac{d}{2}+\epsilon}}$$

I have already proved that thm 2 implies thm 1, but I'm stuck with thm 1 impies thm 2, Can anybody help me? Thank you

Comment: This Q, and your last comment, are  over a year old. Are you still interested in in A,or did you solve it?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see it

Answer (score 1):

Hint : Suppose, there are infinite many rational numbers $\frac{p}{q}$, such
 that the condition in $2$ holds for given $d$ and $\epsilon$. Then, there
 are fractions $\frac{p}{q}$ with arbitary large $q$ under these fractions.

Comment: ok, Suppose that there are infinitely many rational numbers $\frac{p}{q}$, such that the condition in 2 holds for given $d$ and $\epsilon$, and notice that for each fixed $q$ there are only finitely many integers $p$ such that condition 2 holds, so this implies that there is infinitely many rational numbers $\frac{p}{q}$ such that condition 2 holds and each $q$ is different, so $q$ can be arbitary large.

Comment: Also I noticed that I can assume that $(p,q)=1$ (because for each
   $\frac{p}{q}$ such that condition 2 holds and $(p,q)=1$  there are
   only finitely many couples $s,t\in\mathbb{Z}$, $t>0$ such that
   $\frac{p}{q}=\frac{s}{t}$ and
   $|\xi-\frac{s}{t}|<\frac{1}{t^{1+\frac{d}{2}+\epsilon}}$ )
   
   but I don't know how to continue, this led me to nowhere.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose Theorem 1 to be true and also suppose that there is an algebraic real number $\xi$ of degree $d\geq 3$ and an $\epsilon >0$ such that there are infinitely many rationals $\frac{p}{q}$ with $q>0$ such that 
$$|\xi-\frac{p}{q}|<\frac{1}{q^{1+\frac{d}{2}+\epsilon}}.$$

Now apply Theorem 1 to $\xi$ and $\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Then there is a number $\gamma >0$ such that
$$|\xi-\frac{p}{q}|>\frac{\gamma}{q^{1+\frac{d}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}}}$$ for all $p,q\in\mathbb{Z}$ $, q>0$.

So there are infinitely many rationals $\frac{p}{q}$ with $q>0$ such that 
$$\frac{1}{q^{1+\frac{d}{2}+\epsilon}} > \frac{\gamma}{q^{1+\frac{d}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}}}.$$

Then $\gamma < q^{-\frac{\epsilon}{2}}$ for infinitely many $q$ and $\gamma$ is therefore zero, a contradiction.